# Show 'all' as drop-down option in SSRS parameters as default and return data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset called Region and it returns a table result like this:

```
ID       Description
1000     1000- Region #1 - Wilmington
2000     2000- Region #2 - Dover/Cove
9900     9900- Unknown
```

So I want to show these requirement values:
The Region drop-down on the Reports parameters should not be showing 9900-Unknown.
The drop-down should only show:

```
**ALL
Region #1 - Wilmington
Region #2 - Dover/Cove**
```

It should not have 1000, 2000 or --Deselect All --
The --Select All-- should just say ALL
Well I came up with this query solution:

```
SELECT        - 1 AS ID, 'All' AS Description
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Description
FROM            Local
WHERE Description <> 'Unknown'
```

However I am not able to see any data when I select 'ALL' in the drop-down but with other selections it works fine. What might be the issue?  Can someone help me fix this issue.
Yes I tried this code:

```
SELECT -1 AS ID, 'ALL' AS Description
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Description
FROM Local where  EndDate = '12/30/3999'
and right(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID), 2) = '00' AND Description <> 'Unknown';
```

Results:

```
ID    Description 
-1    ALL
1000  Region #1 - Wilmington 
2000  Region #2 - Dover/Cove
```

Please help me fix this issue

Comment: What is your main query calling the parameter?

Comment: The code you shared only appears to be to get the parameter values listed correctly. In your main dataset query you would typically need something like `WHERE (RegionID = @Region or @Region = -1)`

Comment: the main query calling the parameter is Region and it has to to have 3 drop-down ALL, Region #1 - Wilmington, Region #2 - Dover/Cove and when selecting ALL, Region #1 - Wilmington and  Region #2 - Dover/Cove  need to be automatically selected to pull all the data but when trying it , it does not bring the data from the ALL drop-down